# Finding multiple results in a column

Tags: excel-formula

Is there a function to pull the values in column A based on the values of column B where column B only has two values and I only want the True Values. I want the results to populate in like in column D
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFOiQ.jpg)

Comment: Hint: Use IF function: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2. You should show your efforts in solving the problem, so if you have tried some formula just share it to help you fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following array formula in `Cell D1`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$8, SMALL(IF(TRUE=$B$1:$B$8, ROW($A$1:$A$8), ""), ROW(A1))),"")
```

Being an array formula you'll have to commit above formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy down as reuired.

See image for reference

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following Array formula will give you the desired results that you have in your Example.It can be entered in D1 and copied down as far as your names reside in Column A:

=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:A$24,SMALL(IF(B$1:B$24=TRUE,ROW(B$1:B$24),""),ROW())),"")

( Confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter in D1 )